# Injecting random values as one input feature for feature selection results in a odd beaviour

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, decision-trees, xgboost, gbm

I am trying to find a cutoff value, in the feature importance space to eliminate spurious features. So I am injecting a completely random generated feature (as one of the input features) and I cut the features that are scoring below the value of the random feature in the importance ranking. But once I removed the features, the performance drop. I don't understand what is happening. I checked this behavior in a gradient boost and in a random forest. Someone has a clue of what is happening?

Comment: How are you measuring performance here?  And performance of what exactly?

Comment: multi log loss. in this case "drop" means the log loss is greater.

Comment: Could you add some details - size of data set, number of features, nature of target variable (I assume classification - but how many targets) nature of random feature (random hot-encoded class or random real value) how you are splitting train/cv/test and which measurement were getting worse (log loss of *which* data sets - train, cv or test), and finally what sort of performance are you getting with the model before attempting this improvement? I'm not saying all of them are relevant, however I think size and shape of original data is likely to be.